# How to write a program that outputs source code

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

This might not be the right place for this to ask, but I am interested in artificial neural networks and want to learn more.

How do you design a network and train it on source code so it can come up with programs for, for example, easy number theory problems?

What's the general name of this research field?

Comment: I understand that you want to write a program generator based on neural networks, after training with sample programs, that will solve number theory problems, right ? If true, your question is very naive, for at least two reasons. 1) Neural networks do not deal with strings of characters and even less well-formed grammatical expressions, 2) programs that look alike will not necessarily produce similar results (most programs synthetized this way will just fail or loop forever).

Comment: The area that you (probably) want to address is called *Automatic Problem Solving*. (Also related to *Automated Theorem Proving*, which is not really a branch of AI.)

Comment: Thank you fot the quick answer.
1) I am aware that neural networks do not deal with strings, but what if the model has N output nodes which represent basic programming blocks (loops, conditional jumps, etc) and depending on which of those nodes are triggered you synthesized code.

Comment: This is similar to letting an army of chimpanzees type randomly until one of them writes the bible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hugely interesting, and very hard, problem area. It will probably take you months to read enough to even understand how to attack the problem. Here's a few things that might help you get started, and they are more to show the problems you will face than to provide solutions:

http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/

Then read this, and related papers:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5401v2.pdf

Next, you probably want to read the classic papers in program synthesis and generation at the parse tree/AST level (mostly out of MIT, I think, in the early 90s.)

Best of luck. This is not trivial.

Comment: I learned about parser/compilers and AST last semester where i got the idea from.
The synthesis might not be the hard part (dont get stuck in loops / Halte-Problem) but the question is what do you try to synthesize...

Comment: As I said, it's hard to even understand how to attack the problem :) You could a) find a big code base, assume small changes are bug fixes and try to predict if blocks of code have bugs in them - that would be cool! b) read up on Eurisko, and try to figure out how to make a modern version using ANNs.